# Record a value when date condition is met

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have been trying in many ways but I have not been successful to record the results of a constantly changing cell.

This is the case: Cell A1 value is changing, (Value changes daily and depends on other external variables) and I need to record the value of A1 at specific points in time. Cell B1 contains the actual date (Today()).
I have a table with specific dates in a column (01/01/2024 to 31/12/2024). I need to record the result of A1 when the actual date meet the criteria in the table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

I have tried to use If statements and some VBA coding, but with unsatisfactory results.

This is the code I am working with

```
Public Sub RecordMacro()

For Each d In Range("A3:A368")

If (d.Value = Range("$B$2").Value) And (Abs(DateDiff("d", d.Offset(0, 1).Value, Range("$B$2").Value)) = 0) Then
d.Offset(0, 2).Value = Range("A1").Value

End If

Next

AlertTime = Now + TimeValue("24:00:00")
Application.OnTime AlertTime, "RecordMacro"

End Sub
```

[image: Reference Picture]

Comment: Please edit your post to share the code.

Comment: Done, that's the code I've been trying to make work

Comment: What's the purpose of the 2nd condition `(Abs(DateDiff("d", d.Offset(0, 1).Value, Range("$B$2").Value)) = 0)`? `d.Offset(0, 1)` is a cell in column B, it comes from A1. `Range("$B$2")` is a date. It doesn't make any scence to compare it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but here's what I think you're trying to do:

1. A1 is an integer [e.g. 60] and changes daily.
2. B1 is just today's date [i.e. Excel formula =TODAY()].
3. You have a table with two columns: range A3:A368 contains dates for the year of 2024 and range B3:B368 contains the desired integers similar to A1.
4. You want to be notified when the integer in A1 matches the integer in your table. In other words, if the dates match and the integers match then notify me.

I hope this helps:

Let's say today is 2024-01-01, A1 is 60 and you are looking for 60 for that date [A3,B3]. The code below would output 'True for 2024-01-01' in the Immediate window and record the value in column C.

[image: Input and output screenprint]

```
Sub scheduleRun()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "RecordMacro" 'Runs Sub RecordMacro() 5 seconds from now
    'Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("24:00:00"), "RecordMacro" 'Runs Sub RecordMacro() 24 hours from now
End Sub

Sub RecordMacro()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each d In ws.Range("A3:A368")
        'If column A date = B1 date AND the integer in A1 = the integer in column B. In other words, check if today's integer matches what you desire for the day
        If d.Value = ws.Range("B1").Value And Abs(DateDiff("d", d.Offset(0, 1).Value, ws.Range("A1").Value)) = 0 Then
            'For example: if today were 2024-01-01, A1=60, and B3=60, then this would print True for 2024-01-01
            Debug.Print True & " for " & Format(d.Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
            d.Offset(0, 2).Value = Range("A1").Value
            'Here you can also add code depending on how you'd like to be notified
        End If
    Next
End Sub

''This commented out code is to help populate the table from your screenprint.
'Sub fillTable()
'    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
'    'Starting on row 3, fill column A with dates for year 2024 and column B with random integers inclusive from 1 to 100 (randomized based on system timer)
'    Dim d As Date, row As Integer: row = 3: For d = DateSerial(2024, 1, 1) To DateSerial(2024, 12, 31): ws.Cells(row, 1) = d: ws.Cells(row, 2) = Int((100 * Rnd) + 1): row = row + 1: Next: ws.Columns(1).NumberFormat = "yyyy\-mm\-dd": ws.Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
'End Sub
```

Insert the subs into a module [right click on Microsoft Excel Objects on the left side in Developer Mode -> Insert -> Module -> paste code].

Comment: Exactly what I needed, it is the right answer, thank you very much for your time.